# Mostrar el nombre de cada carrera y la cantidad de alumnos de cada carrera

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Esta es mi consulta:

```
select carrera,count(*) as codigo 
from alumnos
group by carrera;
```

La misma, me muestra el código de la carrera y la cantidad de alumnos.

Necesito intercambiar el código de la carrera por su nombre que se encuentra en otra tabla.

La tabla es`carreras` que incluye los campos `código`, `nombre facultad`.

De esta tabla el campo `nombre` es el que necesito incorporar al código enviado.

Comment: Bienvenido Antoine, por favor puedes hace un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. también seria bueno que vayas a [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Tal como está solo te llevará a puntuaciones negativas y reportes.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.nombre, count(*) as Total
from alumnos a inner join 
carreras c on 
a.idCarrera = c.idCarrera
group by c.nombre
```

En esta consulta lo que se hace es mediante la **cláusula inner join** juntar ambas tablas por el campo que las relaciona, posteriormente se agrupa por el nombre de la carrera y por último se muestra en el **select** el campo que tiene el nombre de la carrera y el total de registros por cada grupo.